# после разборки шаблона bootstrap подключенного к джанго отвалился фон и скрипты

Tags: django

после разборки шаблона bootstrap отвалился фон и скрипты, помогите найти ошибку
main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    {% block title_page %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}" type="image/png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="img/x-icon">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,800italic,700italic,600italic,400italic,300italic,800,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'css/responsive.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.isotope.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/wow.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/classie.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/magnific-popup.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'contactform/contactform.js"></script>

    <!-- =======================================================
    Theme Name: Knight
    Theme URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/knight-free-bootstrap-theme/
    Author: BootstrapMade
    Author URL: https://bootstrapmade.com
    ======================================================= -->
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="main-nav-outer" id="test">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#header">Домашня сторінка</a></li>
                <li><a href="#service">Послуги</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Portfolio">Галерея</a></li>
                <li class="small-logo"><a href="#header"><img src="{% static 'img/small-logo.png' %}" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#client">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Контакти</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="res-nav_click" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {% block content%}
    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
    {% extends "layouts/main.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block title_page %}
    <title> Головна</title>
    {% endblock title_page%}
    {% block content%}


<body>
    <header class="header" id="header">
        <!--header-start-->
        <div class="container">
            <figure class="logo animated fadeInDown delay-07s">
                <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h1 class="animated fadeInDown delay-07s">Ната та фарби</h1>
            <ul class="we-create animated fadeInUp delay-1s">
                <li>Зроби своє життя кольоровим</li>
            </ul>
            <a class="link animated fadeInUp delay-1s servicelink" href="#service">Get Started</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="main-section" id="service">
        <!--main-section-start-->
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Послуги</h2>
            <h6>We offer exceptional service with complimentary hugs.</h6>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeft delay-05s">
                    <div class="service-list">
                        <div class="service-list-col1">
                            <i class="fa fa-paw"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="service-list-col2">PORTFOLIO
                            <h3>branding &amp; identity</h3>
                            <p>Proin iaculis purus digni consequat sem digni ssim. Donec entum digni ssim.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-list">
                        <div class="service-list-col1">
                            <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="service-list-col2">
                            <h3>web development</h3>
                            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem digni ssim. Digni ssim porttitora .</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-list">
                        <div class="service-list-col1">
                            <i class="fa fa-apple"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="service-list-col2">
                            <h3>mobile design</h3>
                            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat digni sem digni ssim. Purus donec porttitora entum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-list">
                        <div class="service-list-col1">
                            <i class="fa fa-medkit"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="service-list-col2">
                            <h3>24/7 Support</h3>
                            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem digni ssim. Sem porttitora entum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <figure class="col-lg-8 col-sm-6  text-right wow fadeInUp delay-02s">
                    <img src="img/macbook-pro.png' %}" alt="">
                </figure>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="main-section alabaster">
        <!--main-section alabaster-start-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <figure class="col-lg-5 col-sm-4 wow fadeInLeft">
                    <img src="{% static 'img/iphone.png' %}" alt="">
                </figure>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 featured-work">
                    <h2>featured work</h2>
                    <P class="padding-b">Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit.</P>
                    <div class="featured-box">
                        <div class="featured-box-col1 wow fadeInRight delay-02s">
                            <i class="fa fa-magic"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-box-col2 wow fadeInRight delay-02s">
                            <h3>magic of theme development</h3>
                            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-box">
                        <div class="featured-box-col1 wow fadeInRight delay-04s">
                            <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-box-col2 wow fadeInRight delay-04s">
                            <h3>neatly packaged</h3>
                            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-box">
                        <div class="featured-box-col1 wow fadeInRight delay-06s">
                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-box-col2 wow fadeInRight delay-06s">
                            <h3>SEO optimized</h3>
                            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="Learn-More" href="#">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="main-section client-part" id="client">
        <!--main-section client-part-start-->
        <div class="container">
            <b class="quote-right wow fadeInDown delay-03"><i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i></b>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p class="client-part-haead wow fadeInDown delay-05">It was a pleasure to work with the guys at Knight Studio. They made sure we were well fed and drunk all the time!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="client wow fadeIn delay-05s">
                <li><a href="#">
                <img src="{% static 'img/client-pic1.jpg' %}" alt="">
                <h3>James Bond</h3>
                <span>License To Drink Inc.</span>
            </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="c-logo-part">
        <!--c-logo-part-start-->
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/c-liogo1.png' %}" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/c-liogo2.png' %}" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/c-liogo3.png' %}" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/c-liogo4.png' %}" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/c-liogo5.png' %}" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="business-talking">
        <!--business-talking-start-->
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Let’s Talk Business.</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="main-section contact" id="contact">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-7 wow fadeInLeft">
                    <div class="contact-info-box address clearfix">
                        <h3><i class=" icon-map-marker"></i>Address:</h3>
                        <span>308 Negra Arroyo Lane<br>Albuquerque, New Mexico, 87111.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-info-box phone clearfix">
                        <h3><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone:</h3>
                        <span>1-800-BOO-YAHH</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-info-box email clearfix">
                        <h3><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>email:</h3>
                        <span>hello@knightstudios.com</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-info-box hours clearfix">
                        <h3><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Hours:</h3>
                        <span><strong>Monday - Thursday:</strong> 10am - 6pm<br><strong>Friday:</strong> People work on Fridays now?<br><strong>Saturday - Sunday:</strong> Best not to ask.</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social-link">
                        <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="pinterest"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="gplus"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 wow fadeInUp delay-05s">
                    <div class="form">

                        <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                        <div id="errormessage"></div>
                        <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control input-text text-area" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="input-btn">Send Message</button></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-logo"><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/footer-logo.png' %}" alt=""></a></div>
            <span class="copyright">&copy; Knight Theme. All Rights Reserved</span>
            <div class="credits">
                <!--
          All the links in the footer should remain intact.
          You can delete the links only if you purchased the pro version.
          Licensing information: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
          Purchase the pro version with working PHP/AJAX contact form: https://bootstrapmade.com/buy/?theme=Knight
        -->
                Designed by <a href="https://bootstrapmade.com/">BootstrapMade</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {

            $('#test').scrollToFixed();
            $('.res-nav_click').click(function() {
                $('.main-nav').slideToggle();
                return false

            });

      $('.Portfolio-box').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image'
      });

        });
    </script>

    <script>
        wow = new WOW({
            animateClass: 'animated',
            offset: 100
        });
        wow.init();
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {

            $('.main-nav li a, .servicelink').bind('click', function(event) {
                var $anchor = $(this);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 102
                }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
                /*
                if you don't want to use the easing effects:
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1000);
                */
                if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                    $('.main-nav').hide();
                }
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        })
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {


            var $container = $('.portfolioContainer'),
                $body = $('body'),
                colW = 375,
                columns = null;


            $container.isotope({
                // disable window resizing
                resizable: true,
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: colW
                }
            });

            $(window).smartresize(function() {
                // check if columns has changed
                var currentColumns = Math.floor(($body.width() - 30) / colW);
                if (currentColumns !== columns) {
                    // set new column count
                    columns = currentColumns;
                    // apply width to container manually, then trigger relayout
                    $container.width(columns * colW)
                        .isotope('reLayout');
                }

            }).smartresize(); // trigger resize to set container width
            $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function() {
                $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');

                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({

                    filter: selector,
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
    {% endblock content %}
</body>

</html>
```

консоль:
[18/Apr/2021 20:42:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2912
Not Found: /{% static 'contactform/contactform.js
[18/Apr/2021 20:42:44] "GET /%7B%%20static%20'contactform/contactform.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3359
Not Found: /{% static 'contactform/contactform.js
[18/Apr/2021 20:42:44] "GET /%7B%%20static%20'contactform/contactform.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3359

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в базовом файле

```
<script src="{% static 'contactform/contactform.js"></script>
```

вы забыли поставить `' %}`

Правильный вариан `<script src="{% static 'contactform/contactform.js' %}"></script>`